# Navigation menu access control through DB - Apex oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have a table with Page and its page numbers stored in it. I want to show only those bars on the navigation menu whose page numbers are assigned to the end user. How can I do it? 
I'm using Apex 19.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function which returns a Boolean, saying whether certain user can (or can not) access certain page, e.g.

```
create table t_access as
  select 1 page_no, 'LITTLE' app_user, 'Y' yn from dual union all  --> can access page 1
  select 2 page_no, 'LITTLE' app_user, 'N' yn from dual;           --> can NOT access page 2

create or replace function f_access(par_page_no in number, par_app_user in varchar2)
  return boolean 
as
  l_yn t_access.yn%type;
begin
  select a.yn
    into l_yn
    from t_access a
    where a.page_no = par_page_no
      and a.app_user = par_app_user;
  return l_yn = 'Y';
exception
  when no_data_found then
    return false;
end;
```

Use that function in navigation list entry's **conditions** property; make it a "PL/SQL function body returning a Boolean" as

```
    return f_access(1, :APP_USER);
```